# Merging two dataframes that have only one column that names the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am new at merging dataframes.
I want to compare two dataframes:

left:

```
    A
0   a
1   b
2   d
```

right

```
    A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
```

I want something like this:

```
    A   A_1
0   a   a
1   b   b
2   NaN c
3   d   d
```

Is it possible to do this using merge/join/compare functions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.
What you are asking for is a right outer join/merge.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) detailed overview.

```
df_left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'd']})
df_right = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

df_left.merge(df_right.rename(columns={'A':'A_1'}), left_on='A', right_on='A_1', how='right')
```

Out

```
     A A_1
0    a   a
1    b   b
2  NaN   c
3    d   d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the info about the merge you can use indicator argument of [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='A', indicator=True)

   A      _merge
0  a        both
1  b        both
2  d        both
3  c  right_only
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `join`:

```
>>> left.set_index('A', drop=False) \
        .join(right.set_index('A', drop=False), rsuffix='_1', how='outer') \
        .reset_index(drop=True)

     A A_1
0    a   a
1    b   b
2  NaN   c
3    d   d
```